# Custom WeakReference implementation

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

WeakReference in BCL was designed in pre generics era, so it's interface is not as nice as it could be. Also IsAlive property is very easy to misuse.
Looking into the implementation of WeakReference trough Reflector it seems like we could implement it ourselves.
Here is what I came up with:

```
    [SecurityPermission(Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode)]
    public sealed class WeakRef<T> where T : class
    {
        private readonly volatile IntPtr _ptr;

        public WeakRef(T target)
            : this(target, false)
        {
        }

        [SecuritySafeCritical]
        public WeakRef(T target, bool trackResurrection)
        {
            var handle = GCHandle.Alloc(target, trackResurrection ? GCHandleType.WeakTrackResurrection : GCHandleType.Weak);
            _ptr = GCHandle.ToIntPtr(handle);
        }

        [SecuritySafeCritical]
        ~WeakRef()
        {
            var ptr = _ptr;
            if ((ptr != IntPtr.Zero) && (ptr == Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _ptr, IntPtr.Zero, ptr)))
            {
                var handle = GCHandle.FromIntPtr(ptr);
                handle.Free();
            }
        }

        public T Target
        {
            get
            {
                var ptr = _ptr;
                if (IntPtr.Zero != ptr)
                {
                    var target = GCHandle.FromIntPtr(ptr).Target;
                    if (_ptr != IntPtr.Zero)
                    {
                        return (T)target;
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

but I'm not sure I got the implementation of BCL counterpart right.
Can anyone spot any issues in the code above?

Answer (score 6):

I don't spot anything wrong offhand except adding error handling. However, I prefer this implementation for its simplicity, especially since it uses the BCL version and you don't have to try as hard to "get it right":

```
public sealed class WeakReference<T> where T : class
{
    public WeakReference(T target) : this(target, trackResurrection)
    {}

    public WeakReference(T target, bool trackResurrection)
    {
        refTarget = new WeakReference(target, trackResurrection);
    }

    public T Target { get { return refTarget.Target as T; } }

    public bool IsAlive { get { return refTarget.IsAlive; }}

    private readonly WeakReference refTarget;
}
```

Comment: Do note, though, that the above has the same limitation that it is not disposable as the typeless `WeakReference`. See http://damieng.com/blog/2006/08/01/implementingweakreferencet for a more complex version.

Answer (score 0):

- The `GCHandle` methods could throw exceptions - so make sure you have your `try`/`catches`.
- You could encourage better usage by providing a `TryGetTarget` method.
- Why call it `WeakRef`?

Here is my go at it.

```
public sealed class WeakReference<T> : IDisposable
    where T : class
{
    private volatile IntPtr _handle;
    private GCHandleType _handleType;

    public WeakReference(T target)
        : this(target, false)
    {
    }

    [SecuritySafeCritical]
    public WeakReference(T target, bool trackResurrection)
    {
        if (target == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("target");
        _handleType = trackResurrection ? GCHandleType.WeakTrackResurrection : GCHandleType.Weak;
        Target = target;
    }

    [SecuritySafeCritical]
    ~WeakReference()
    {
        Dispose();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        var ptr = _handle;
        if ((ptr != IntPtr.Zero) &&
            Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _handle, IntPtr.Zero, ptr) == ptr)
        {
            try
            {
                var handle = GCHandle.FromIntPtr(ptr);
                if (handle.IsAllocated)
                    handle.Free();
            }
            catch
            { }
        }
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    public bool TryGetTarget(out T target)
    {
        var ptr = _handle;
        if (ptr != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            try
            {
                var handle = GCHandle.FromIntPtr(ptr);
                if (handle.IsAllocated)
                {
                    target = (T)handle.Target;
                    return !object.ReferenceEquals(target, null);
                }
            }
            catch
            { }
        }
        target = null;
        return false;
    }

    public bool TryGetTarget(out T target, Func<T> recreator)
    {
        IntPtr ptr = _handle;
        try
        {
            var handle = GCHandle.FromIntPtr(ptr);
            if (handle.IsAllocated)
            {
                target = (T)handle.Target;
                if (!object.ReferenceEquals(target, null))
                    return false;
            }
        }
        catch
        { }

        T createdValue = null;
        target = null;

        while ((ptr = _handle) == IntPtr.Zero || object.ReferenceEquals(target, null))
        {
            createdValue = createdValue ?? recreator();
            var newPointer = GCHandle.Alloc(createdValue, _handleType).AddrOfPinnedObject();
            if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _handle, newPointer, ptr) == ptr)
            {
                target = createdValue;
                return true;
            }
            else if ((ptr = _handle) != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                try
                {
                    var handle = GCHandle.FromIntPtr(ptr);
                    if (handle.IsAllocated)
                    {
                        target = (T)handle.Target;
                        if (!object.ReferenceEquals(target, null))
                            return false;
                    }
                }
                catch
                { }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public bool IsAlive
    {
        get
        {
            var ptr = _handle;
            return ptr != IntPtr.Zero && GCHandle.FromIntPtr(ptr).IsAllocated;
        }
    }

    public T Target
    {
        get
        {
            T target;
            TryGetTarget(out target);
            return target;
        }
        set
        {
            Dispose();
            _handle = GCHandle.Alloc(value, _handleType).AddrOfPinnedObject();
            GC.ReRegisterForFinalize(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Jonathan, I don't see how my implementation can benefit from exception handling, could you elaborate on this?

Comment: How TryGetTarget is better than plain Target property? You need to perform a check in both cases.

Comment: @ubiq - the MSDN documentation states that exceptions could be thrown. The actual WeakReference uses internal calls, which we don't have access to. Also, the following code is buggy, and if you don't understand why you shouldn't be writing a WeakReference class: `if(ref.Target != null) ref.Target.DoSomething();`

Comment: If something throws it doesn't mean you always have to catch it. You didn't state how swallowing the exception improves the code. TryGetTarget is not much better because someone can write something similar to your code: 
`myClass t = null;
ref.TryGetTarget(out t);
t.DoSomething();`

Comment: @ubiq swallowing the exception makes this class consistent with the built in weakreference.

Comment: the built in one doesn't catch any exceptions at least according to .NET Reflector.

Comment: @ubiq I give up - the built in one uses **internal method calls that you do not have access to**. MSDN states that the method calls you are using could throw exceptions.

Comment: @ubiq - just confirmed that in .Net 4.5 the target object is guarded by `TryGetTarget`, **EXACTLY** as I suggested (infact the `Target` property isn't even there). `TryGetTarget` could be mis-used but it is less likely to be.